# NginxとPHPでサイト公開したいのですが、

Tags: php, apache, nginx

**前提とする組み合わせ**
・CentOS7
・PHP7
・Nginx

---

**調べてみたら下記2通りあるように思うのですが(これ以外にもある？？)、それぞれのメリットデメリットを知りたい**
fastcgi(PHP-FPM？)と組み合わせることで、全内容をnginxが返す

静的内容をnginxが返す。動的内容は普通のPHPがapacheへパスして返す
・[Webサーバのnginxで静的コンテンツ配信とキャッシュコントロール](http://kray.jp/blog/nginx/)

Comment: 細かい部分ですが、2つ目の「Apacheへパスして～」はNginxの間違いでしょうか？

Comment: 2つ目は「Nginx」と「Apache」を併用するやり方の意味で質問しました。内容は理解できていないです。質問本文にリンク追記しました